# accessing Jenkins HTML report

Tags: html, selenium, jenkins, plugins

I have a Jenkins job which uses HTML publisher plugin and executes selenium automation cases and generates a HTML test result report link on Jenkins job details page. i want to pass this HTML report link to stakeholder who can view the report without logging in to Jenkins server but the problem is all the stakeholders  may not have Jenkins account/login setup so is there a way to bypass the authentication part and directly access the html report link(make the report public) which is on Jenkins.
any help highly appreciated..

Comment: You could send the generated report as an email, using `Email-ext` plugin

Comment: how about hipchat or slack notification. works best. and yes, email-ext plugin with groovy script is a better option too.

Comment: N00bPr0grammer,   sending email is not the preferred option for us.   
 @GaurangShah  and regarding slack, yes i'm already sending the html report link in slack channel only to all the stakeholders. thats where i landed in to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can configure this from global security setting in Jenkins. if you are Admin you will have access to this, if not you need to ask your Jenkins Admin for it.

```
http://<JenkinsHost>/configureSecurity/
```

Give read-only permission to **Anonymous** Users for Job should fix the issue. I haven't tested it but it should work I guess.

**Caveat**: if Jenkins is deployed on public domain or cloud anyone having access to Jenkins URL will be able to see your job and all the important information mentioned in Job Config. So I would not suggest to do it. if it's on private domain, I don't see much risk.

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works. and the Jenkins server is within our firewall so we are good :)